# What is the correct way to test javascript with unit AND integrations tests, using Visual Studio and Team City?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, teamcity, jasmine, karma-runner

I have got javascript tests running in visual studio using Resharper and Jasmine. It all works fine. Now however I want to run an integration test. After looking into this I just can't work out whether I should be using Karma or PhantomJs or both? And whether they link to resharper?

I then have to run all my tests on the continuous integration server using Team City. Doesn't seem like there is a clear logical way to architect front end testing from dev right through to the CI server.

For example do I really need to use Karma locally and on the CI server? I don't want to because it is not baked into visual studio and I will have to keep opening the command line and running my tests manually. This will annoy other developers and they won't bother running them I imagine. Help!

We are using Team City by the way....

Answer (score 0):

Neither of these test runners are connected to Resharper in any form. I don't think there is a one and only "correct" way of running Jasmine tests in TeamCity currently - for all approaches I am aware of there is a bit of assembly required.

Personally I am using a combination of PhantomJS and the [Jasmine TeamCity Reporter](https://github.com/EmberConsultingGroup/JasmineTeamCityReporter) which works like this:

- Get a list of unique test URLs from server - each of these test suites will use the Jasmine TeamCity Reporter to log results
- for each test URL dynamically generate a test JS file to be used for phantom and write it to disk
- use PhantomJS to run the JS file which now will load the test suite page and its test result will be written to console where they are picked up by TeamCity.